# how to get matching array values in php

Tags: php

Q1: how to display the matching values?

array 1:

```
Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 10 [2] => 11 [3] => 12 [4] => 13 [5] => 14 [6] => 15 [7] => 16 )
```

array 2:

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 [3] => 11 [4] => 12 [5] => 13 [6] => 14 [7] => 15 [8] => 16 [9] => 17 [10] => 18 [11] => 19 [12] => 20 [13] => 21 [14] => 22 [15] => 23 )
```

output:

09-16

how to display matching first value and last value in the array

Comment: I've formatted the code so you can at least read it.

Comment: @MattHarrison It's hardly code :-P

Comment: Did you even try to google it? `array_intersect` is the first result with your exact question as the query!

Comment: @BenCarey Well, ya know…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get the Matching Values in the Arrays

Use `array_intersect()` to return the matching values.

See documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Example:

```
// Get the matching values
$matching_values = array_intersect($array1,$array2);

// This will print the matching values in the arrays
print_r($matching_values);
```

### Get the Non-Matching Values in the arrays

Use `array_diff()` to return the differences the arrays.

See documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Example:

```
// Get the non-matching values
$differences = array_diff($array1,$array2);

// This will print the differences in the arrays
print_r($differences);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$matching = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($matching);
```

[`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect)

Comment: i am just for checking.

Comment: how to get fist value and last value in the matching array

Comment: You use [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) and [`end()`](http://php.net/end)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$arr = array_intersect(array1,array2);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: then how to display only this value 09-16 from the matching array